# Deploy Mobile App to Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, deployment

I am new in the mobile apps world and i wanted to know how to deploy my app after being developed to Google App Engine.

I read many things but i am lost and there is no getting started guides for the points after development.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As i have seen in Uploading APP to google play store, it is straightforward to upload. It is like form to fill up.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to generate a `keystore` for your application. From the [Android documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20141124162044/http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> Android requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate
> before they can be installed. Android uses this certificate to
> identify the author of an app, and the certificate does not need to be
> signed by a certificate authority.

Here's a good guide from Google:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

The Google Play Developer Console is your home for publishing operations and tools. You can manage all phases of publishing on Google Play through it.

That will help you to publish your app:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html